# Prove that $g$ has a limit at $x_0$ if $f$ has a limit at $x_0$ and $\lim_{t\to x_0} f(t)=f(x_0)$

Tags: analysis

The problem:

Suppose $f:[a,b]\to R$ and define $g: [a,b]\to R$ as follows:

$g(x)=\sup \{f(t):a\le t\le x \}$

Prove that $g$ has a limit at $x_0$ if $f$ has a limit at $x_0$ and $\lim_{t\to x_o}f(t)=f(x_0)$.

What I have so far (after assuming the givens):

Suppose $f$ has a limit at $x_0$ and $\lim_{t\to x_o}f(t)=f(x_0)$.
Then for all $\epsilon >0$, there exists $\delta >0$ such that for all $0<\lvert t-x_0\rvert <\delta \Rightarrow \lvert f(t)-f(x_0)\rvert <\epsilon$.

Not sure where to go from here...Do I suppose $x_0<x<x_0+\delta$ or $x_0-\delta<x<x_0$ and if $g(x)=g(x_0)$, and prove by cases?

Edit: If anyone else can provide possibly additional input, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Your question says that $f$ is continuous at $x_{0}$. Show that $g$ is continuous wherever $f$ is continuous. This is already asked on MSE. Will try to find it and post here.

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/a/808466/72031 You will also need the constraint that $f$ is bounded (otherwise $g$ will be undefined).

Comment: That's not the same question, although it's similar. I haven't started proving continuity in my class yet.

Comment: Yeah its not the same question but the proof in my answer applies to your question too. Saying that $\lim_{t \to x_{0}}f(t) = f(x_{0})$ is just another way to say that *$f$ is continuous at $x_{0}$*. Continuity does not have any extra meaning apart from this.